# How to unbind Command-Control-Space key from Mac OS X 10.9?

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks

How can I unbind Command-Control-Space from Mac OS X 10.9?

This shortcut shows Special Characters table and conflicts with my Emacs key binding, and I couldn't disable it from `System Preference->Keyboard->Shortcuts`.

Thanks.

Comment: this isn't about programming or software development, it should be on [apple.se]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can create custom keyboard shortcuts for most app's menubar choices in System Preferences. If a desired key combination is losing precedence to a default shortcut that you don't use and can't easily disable, simply override it with a new, unobtrusive shortcut.

Open `System Prefs / Keyboard / Shortcuts`. Select `App Shortcuts` from the left pane. Toggle the `All Applications` category's triangle in the main window to point downward (if it's not open already).

If there's an item named `Emoji & Symbols`* shown there, then click its shortcut combination and enter a new shortcut (such as option-shift-command-t, in this case).

If there's not an item named `Emoji & Symbols` under `All Applications`, click the `+` button at the bottom, type or copy-paste `Emoji & Symbols`, and then enter a new keyboard shortcut (option-shift-command-t, or anything really). This will free the control-command-space combination for you to use as a specialized shortcut elsewhere.

To remove your custom shortcut, just click to highlight it in the main window of this preference pane, and click the `–` button at the bottom. The custom shortcut will disappear and the default action will resume.

*Note: On versions older than Mac OS 10.10.3, the menu item is called `Special Characters…` instead of `Emoji & Symbols`.

Comment: This advice was helpful in stopping (unused) Outlook from opening when I hit the wrong key combo for Chrome Developer Tools: added cmd-shift-I as a Chrome shortcut and now Outlook doesn't open when I hold shift instead of option.

Comment: You are my hero. Thanks! I had been told this particular shortcut was not replaceable.

Answer (score 44):

At least on macOS Sierra to macOS Sonoma <kbd>⌃Space</kbd> is the default binding for *Select the previous input source* which is on by default (even if only one input source is activated).

You can free it by:

1. Open System Preferences
2. Go to Keyboard > Shortcuts > Input Sources
3. Untick "Select the previous input source"

Afterwards, you should be able to bind it as expected.

Comment: I have tried unticking it, but apps still don't receive `^space`.. Is there a trick to unbind it? Using Catalina

Comment: It's so annoying that it restores the default key binding once you switch to other language keyboard, even you've made the config

Comment: I had to untick it twice! I only had one language. 
Untick. 
The entire "Input sources" shortcut category disappeared.
Still not receiving `^ Space`. 
Added another input source. Unticked the input source switch input shortcut again.
Receiving `^ Space`! Removed the extra input source. 
Thanks Apple!

Comment: I had to reboot before the setting took effect.

Comment: I got fed up without this feature. You're gem.  Thanks @einSelbst

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to disable this, but an alternative option might be to create a shortcut for the app you want to use that in. I created a Command-Control-Space shortcut for Chrome and now Command-Control-Space doesn't bring up the special character palette anymore in Chrome.

failing that you may be better off asking in [Apple Stackexchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/)